# how to add commas between names in an array using join method-Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This may be super dumb question, but need help on this.
How can I join the names of the users below and separate it by `","`?

code:

```
var users = ["fer", "jyujyu", "jhwevhfwfv"]

    <div>
      {users.map(function(user){
                  return <span key={user}className="user">{user}</span>
                })}
              </div>
```

Where can I apply the join here to add commas between names:
expected o/p:

```
fer, jyujyu, jhwevhfwfv
```

Comment: `<span key={user}className="user">{user} , </span>` will work but adds extra `,` after last. So you just need to handle that using if else or last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to map if you just want to display all the items in the array.

`var users = ["fer", "jyujyu", "jhwevhfwfv"]`

using [array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) you should be able to display all items in a span

`users.join(', ')` will give you the expected output, this joins all items of the array with what you specified and it returns a string.

putting everything together.

```
var users = ["fer", "jyujyu", "jhwevhfwfv"]

<div>
  {
    <span className="user">{users.join(', ')}</span>
  }
</div>
```

here is the link to the sandbox of this working https://codesandbox.io/s/znrj1nopox

Answer (score 2):

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3].join(",").split("");

const listItems = numbers.map(number => (
    <span key={number.toString()}>{number}</span>
));
console.log(listItems);
return <div>{listItems}</div>;
```

I have updated the answer. Since join converts array into string we cant directly render in react component. i have converted to an array to avoid this problem. See the below working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ymvl8olpxx

Comment: He wants to wrap in spans

Comment: included the span wrapping.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ${user} ?

Comment: Will this generate `<span>` elements or will it generate the string `"<span>"`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do with `reduce`:

```
var users = ["fer", "jyujyu", "jhwevhfwfv"]
<div>
  {
    users
      .map(function(user){
              return <span key={user} className="user">{user}</span>
            })
      .reduce(function(prev, next){
        if(Array.isArray(prev))
          return prev.concat(<span>, </span>).concat(next)
        else return [prev, (<span>, </span>), next]
    })
  }
</div>;
```

[Here is a **codepen** example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwzVVe)

Comment: That looks wonky. Why not  `users
   .map(function(user){
       return \`<span key=${user}className="user">${user}</span>\`
   })
   .join(",")`

Comment: You can do it that way. But remember that your comma has no element tag.

Comment: I assume your code is React - will the return really work like that?

Comment: If not React, your JS in not valid is what I meant to say.

Comment: @mplungjan: yes Im able to return the user names and list them, however with just space and no commas, I wanted to insert commas in between

Comment: @mplungjan: i tried your way, it gives [object Object] instead of names, any clue?

Comment: @user1234 none. Workd in plain JS

Comment: OK. I've update the answer with React. Thanks @mplungjan give me a chance to experience how React render view.

Comment: But that code is so complicated. And won't that show two commas? And why not just pop the last comma or shift the first one?

Comment: I added another way. please check

Comment: @user1234 to avoid [object Object] you need an array. see my updated answer with working example.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to do something like so (built upon a previous answer):

```
var users = ["fer", "jyujyu", "jhwevhfwfv"];
var spannedUsers = users.map((user) => <span key={user} className="user">{user}</span>);
<div>
    {spannedUsers.join(", ")}
</div>
```